# How do I combine 2 select statements into one?

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

I am a noob when it comes to SQL syntax.

I have a table with lots of rows and columns of course :P
Lets say it looks like this:

```
      AAA BBB CCC DDD
-----------------------
Row1 | 1   A   D   X
Row2 | 2   B   C   X
Row3 | 3   C   D   Z
```

Now I want to create an advanced select statement that gives me this combined (pseudo SQLish here):

```
select 'Test1', * from TABLE Where CCC='D' AND DDD='X'
select 'Test2', * from TABLE Where CCC<>'D' AND DDD='X'
```

The output would be:

```
Test1, 1, A, D, X
Test2, 2, B, C, X
```

How would I combine those two select statements into one nice select statement?

Would it work if I complicated the SQL like below (because my own SQL statement contains an exists statement)? I just want to know how I can combine the selects and then try to apply it to my somewhat more advanced SQL.

```
select 'Test1', * from TABLE Where CCC='D' AND DDD='X' AND exists(select ...)
select 'Test2', * from TABLE Where CCC<>'D' AND DDD='X' AND exists(select ...)
```

My REAL SQL statement is this one:

```
select Status, * from WorkItems t1
where  exists (select 1 from workitems t2 where t1.TextField01=t2.TextField01 AND (BoolField05=1) )
AND TimeStamp=(select max(t2.TimeStamp) from workitems t2 where t2.TextField01=t1.TextField01) 
AND TimeStamp>'2009-02-12 18:00:00'
```

which gives me a result. But I want to combine it with a copy of this select statement with an added AND on the end and the 'Status' field would be changed with a string like 'DELETED'.

```
select 'DELETED', * from WorkItems t1
where  exists (select 1 from workitems t2 where t1.TextField01=t2.TextField01 AND (BoolField05=1) )
AND TimeStamp=(select max(t2.TimeStamp) from workitems t2 where t2.TextField01=t1.TextField01) 
AND TimeStamp>'2009-02-12 18:00:00'
AND NOT (BoolField05=1)
```

Comment: +1 that is an extremely well asked question

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You have two choices here.  The first is to have two result sets which will set 'Test1' or 'Test2' based on the condition in the `WHERE` clause, and then `UNION` them together:

```
select 
    'Test1', * 
from 
    TABLE 
Where 
    CCC='D' AND DDD='X' AND exists(select ...)
UNION
select 
    'Test2', * 
from 
    TABLE
Where
    CCC<>'D' AND DDD='X' AND exists(select ...)
```

This might be an issue, because you are going to effectively scan/seek on TABLE twice.

The other solution would be to select from the table once, and set 'Test1' or 'Test2' based on the conditions in TABLE:

```
select 
    case 
        when CCC='D' AND DDD='X' AND exists(select ...) then 'Test1'
        when CCC<>'D' AND DDD='X' AND exists(select ...) then 'Test2'
    end,
    * 
from 
    TABLE 
Where 
    (CCC='D' AND DDD='X' AND exists(select ...)) or
    (CCC<>'D' AND DDD='X' AND exists(select ...))
```

The catch here being that you will have to duplicate the filter conditions in the `CASE` statement and the `WHERE` statement.

Comment: Thanks (im using MS SQL Server 2005). Seems like this is what I am looking for. UNION scans twice, but I can live with that. And I didnt know that the CASE statement could be that advancely used.

Answer (score 12):

If they are from the same table, I think [`UNION`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7118.asp) is the command you're looking for.

(If you'd ever need to select values from columns of different tables, you should look at [`JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp) instead...)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the input. Tried the stuff that has been mentioned here and these are the 2 I got to work:

```
(
select 'OK', * from WorkItems t1
where exists(select 1 from workitems t2 where t1.TextField01=t2.TextField01 AND (BoolField05=1) )
AND TimeStamp=(select max(t2.TimeStamp) from workitems t2 where t2.TextField01=t1.TextField01) 
AND TimeStamp>'2009-02-12 18:00:00'
AND (BoolField05=1)
)
UNION
(
select 'DEL', * from WorkItems t1
where exists(select 1 from workitems t2 where t1.TextField01=t2.TextField01 AND (BoolField05=1) )
AND TimeStamp=(select max(t2.TimeStamp) from workitems t2 where t2.TextField01=t1.TextField01) 
AND TimeStamp>'2009-02-12 18:00:00'
AND NOT (BoolField05=1)
)
```

AND

```
select 
    case
        when
            (BoolField05=1)
    then 'OK'
    else 'DEL'
        end,
        *
from WorkItems t1
Where
            exists(select 1 from workitems t2 where t1.TextField01=t2.TextField01 AND (BoolField05=1) )
            AND TimeStamp=(select max(t2.TimeStamp) from workitems t2 where t2.TextField01=t1.TextField01) 
            AND TimeStamp>'2009-02-12 18:00:00'
```

Which would be the most efficient of these (edit: the second as it only scans the table once), **and is it possible to make it even more efficient**? (The BoolField=1) is really a variable (dyn sql) that can contain any where statement on the table.

I am running on MS SQL 2005. Tried Quassnoi examples but did not work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

```
select t1.* from 
(select * from TABLE Where CCC='D' AND DDD='X') as t1,
(select * from TABLE Where CCC<>'D' AND DDD='X') as t2
```

Another way to do this!

Comment: Simple test of a single column table with 2 rows and using that query to select the first as t1 and second as t2, fails, returns only t1.

Answer (score 2):

```
select Status, * from WorkItems t1
where  exists (select 1 from workitems t2 where t1.TextField01=t2.TextField01 AND (BoolField05=1) )
AND TimeStamp=(select max(t2.TimeStamp) from workitems t2 where t2.TextField01=t1.TextField01) 
AND TimeStamp>'2009-02-12 18:00:00'

UNION

select 'DELETED', * from WorkItems t1
where  exists (select 1 from workitems t2 where t1.TextField01=t2.TextField01 AND (BoolField05=1) )
AND TimeStamp=(select max(t2.TimeStamp) from workitems t2 where t2.TextField01=t1.TextField01) 
AND TimeStamp>'2009-02-12 18:00:00'
AND NOT (BoolField05=1)
```

Perhaps that'd do the trick.  I can't test it from here though, and I'm not sure what version of SQL you're working against.

Answer (score 1):

[The Union command is what you need.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)  If that doesn't work, you may need to refine what environment you are in.

Answer (score 1):

use a case into the select and use in the where close a OR

something like this, I didn't tested it but it should work, I think...

```
select case when CCC='D' then 'test1' else 'test2' end, *
from table
where (CCC='D' AND DDD='X') or (CCC<>'D' AND DDD='X')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you're looking for:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN BoolField05 = 1 THEN Status ELSE 'DELETED' END AS MyStatus, t1.*
FROM WorkItems t1
WHERE (TextField01, TimeStamp) IN(
  SELECT TextField01, MAX(TimeStamp)
  FROM WorkItems t2
  GROUP BY t2.TextField01
  )
AND TimeStamp > '2009-02-12 18:00:00'
```

If you're in Oracle or in MS SQL 2005 and above, then you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN BoolField05 = 1 THEN Status ELSE 'DELETED' END AS MyStatus, t1.*,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TextField01 ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS rn
  FROM WorkItems t1
) to
WHERE rn = 1
```

, it's more efficient.